# How do I check if a variable exists, inside a Function?

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying so check if a variable exists, but inside a function.
I was taught that, to do this, the only thing you needed to do was:

```
'a' in locals()
```

Unfortunately, things turned out to be a little bit more difficult than I expected.

I tried to define a function that included this method.

```
q=[1,2,3]
def f():
    print('q' in locals())
```

When I run this function, it returns:

```
False
```

The problem is, as we can see, that q is a variable, so when I run the same command, but outside the function:

```
'q' in locals()
```

It returns:

```
True
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `def f(): print('q' in globals())` should print `True`.

Comment: Do you need to check the variable name as a sting? Could you just try/except the variable and catch a NameError?

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#locals , "Note that at the module level, locals() and globals() are the same dictionary."  This explains why `locals()` is `True` when you run it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you code the following lines

```
q=[1,2,3]
def f():
    print('q' in locals())
f()
```

Here, variable 'q' is not local to function f() as it is declared outside the function scope.Inside the function, q can be accessed using global.
But, outside the function 'q' is a local variable.
Therefore, when you check inside the function

```
q=[1,2,3]
def f():
    print('q' in locals())
```

it will return False

But if you declare inside the function and check as follow:-

```
def f():
    q=[1,2,3]
    print('q' in locals())
```

It will return True as q is now local to the function.

Also if you check 'q' inside the function as global it will return True as 'q' is declared outside the function and has global scope.

```
q=[1,2,3]
def f():
    print('q' in globals())
f()
```

Output

```
True
```

Comment: if **print('q' in globals())**  returns **False** then variable is not local but if it returns **True** then the variable is local to the function

Answer (score 0):

You may test for the existence of your list `q` in the `globals()` dictionary, since it exists in global scope, not the local scope of your function `f`, i.e.:

```
def f():
    print('q' in globals())
```

As pointed out in the comments, testing the existence of variables using their string names like this is not ideal and you may instead use a try/except:

```
def f():
    try:
        # Do something with q
        print(q)
    except NameError:
        print("Variable not defined")
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use

`hasattr(obj, "var")`

and replace obj with self

```
class test():
    def  __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def check(self, var):
        return hasattr(self, var)

t = test()

print(t.check("a"))
print(t.check("b"))
```

output

```
True
False
```

Comment: The OP is not using a class.